# Traefik's "Basic example with docker-compose" not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

Following [this tutorial](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/user-guides/docker-compose/basic-example/)

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik:v2.5
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  whoami:
    container_name: whoami
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.vws.dev`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
```

When trying on my browser, I can't get a response from :

- http://vws.dev
- http://vws.dev:80
- http://whoami.vws.dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing you configure in your `docker-compose.yml` file can make your browser "know" how to map the name `vws.dev` to your container. If you bring up your compose stack, you can verify it's working using `curl` by explicitly setting the `Host` header, like this:

```
curl -H 'Host: whoami.vws.dev` localhost:80
```

Which on my system prints something like:

```
Hostname: 65df3ef3b7d2
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 172.19.0.3
RemoteAddr: 172.19.0.2:43904
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: whoami.vws.dev
User-Agent: curl/7.76.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Forwarded-For: 172.19.0.1
X-Forwarded-Host: whoami.vws.dev
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Server: 2b2a7ec697d6
X-Real-Ip: 172.19.0.1
```

If you want to be able to visit `http://whoami.vws.dev` in your browser, you would have to somehow map that name to the container's ip address. On a unix-like system, you can generally do this by editing your `/etc/hosts` file; for example, I could modify the entry for `127.0.0.1` by appending `whoami.vws.dev` to the list of names:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost ... whoami.vws.dev
```

With that change, I can run:

```
$ curl whoami.vws.dev
Hostname: 65df3ef3b7d2
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 172.19.0.3
RemoteAddr: 172.19.0.1:43748
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: whoami.vws.dev
User-Agent: curl/7.76.1
Accept: */*
```

For a "real" deployment, you would typically add a DNS entry mapping your desired hostname to the address of your docker host.

Comment: I'm pretty confused, i thougt that was one feature of traefik, so you don't have to modify your local host file. In the end I'm not even sure I should use Traefik. Also this "Basic example" sounds very misleading

Comment: Traefik performs the same role as any other front-end proxy (mapping hostnames and paths to particular backends). It's nice because it's dynamically configured based on container labels, which is very useful in an environment where you are often creating and deleting services. In a small, static docker-compose setup it's not necessarily going to be a big win.